# How to improve SQL query performance where case sensitive comparison is required?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I'm wondering if there is an alternate way that is more performance friendly when trying to do an SQL select statement using a case sensitive condition?

For example:

```
AND REL_USER_01 = 'Test_R1' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

The above takes 1m25s to execute in my select statement while:

```
AND REL_USER_01 = 'Test_R1';
```

Takes less than 1 second.

I'd like to use a statement that would have similar comparison to a  COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, but without the major performance hit. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Specifying the COLLATION on the fly is equivalent to using a function so no index can be used.Create a new column with the respective collation and search that

Comment: Does the need for performance imply that the SQL will be called by a program? Your overall performance depends on the design of your system as a whole, and it may be possible to increase performance by ensuring in code that everything is converted to lowercase before being passed over to SQL, then in SQL you just have to check for the lowercase variant of your char(?) varchar(?) nvarchar(?) etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a computed column and build an index on that:

```
alter table t add REL_USER_01_CS as (REL_USER_01 COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS);

create index idx_t_relusercs on t(REL_USER_01_CS);
```

Then:

```
AND REL_USER_01 = 'Test_R1' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS;
```

should use the index.